# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.onRadioPressed')

Tags: react-native

I'm building radio buttons using my component and the buttons are built fine but the onPress is not working.  I get the error in the title on click of the radio button.  I suspect, based on the error, that 'this' is not what I think it is.  Any help is appreciated.  Here's the relevant code:

```
let radio_props = [
        {label: 'forward', value: 0 },
        {label: 'back', value: 1 }
    ];

<RadioBtn
    radioGroupLabel={'Main Label'}
    radioLabels={radio_props}
    style={styles.radioElement}>
</RadioBtn>
```

Then in my RadioBtn.js file...

> onRadioPressed = (val) => {
>           console.log('VAL:', val);
>           this.setState({selectedValue:val});
>       };
>
> ```
> renderRadios(obj, i) {
>     console.log('OBJ:', obj);
>   return (
>       <View style={styles.firstRadioContainer}>
>           <TouchableOpacity
>               onPress={(value, index) => {
>                   this.onRadioPressed(obj.value)
>               }}
>               underlayColor='#f1c40f'>
>               <Text value={obj.value} style={styles.radio}>{obj.label}</Text>
>           </TouchableOpacity>
>       </View>
>   )
> };
>
> render() {
>
>     let renderedRadios = this.props.radioLabels.map(this.renderRadios);
>
>     return (
>         <View>
>             <View style={styles.radioLabelContainer}>
>                 <Text style={styles.radioLabel}>{this.props.radioGroupLabel}</Text>
>             </View>
>             <View style={styles.radioGrp}>
>                 {renderedRadios}
>             </View>
>         </View>
>     );
> };
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, `this` in renderRadios method is no longer pointing to RadioBtn class because of the way you invoke in the array's map method.

Try changing to the following by using [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
let renderedRadios = this.props.radioLabels.map((o, i) => this.renderRadios(o, i));
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much!